# Google Maps API V2 - Binary XML File line #16 : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to get my very fist Google Maps app using V2 API - my IDE is Eclipse - compiles well, shows up in my VDM (Nexus 7) but when I launch - it crashes.

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.whatson.showme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.whatson.showme.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.whatson.showme.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission       
              android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>   



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*** MY API KEY*****"/>       

        <activity
            android:name="com.whatson.showme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
   </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.whatson.showme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final LatLng LOCATION_BURNABY = new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_SURRREY = new LatLng(49.187500, -122.849000);

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map  = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_SURRREY).title("Find me here!"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick_City(View v) {
        //CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_BURNABY);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_BURNABY, 9);
        map.animateCamera(update);
    }
    public void onClick_Burnaby(View v) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_BURNABY, 14);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }
    public void onClick_Surrey(View v) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_SURRREY, 16);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }

}
```

activity_mail.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log dump:

```
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whatson.showme/com.whatson.showme.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.whatson.showme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  ... 11 more
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=12 length=0
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValue(TypedArray.java:656)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4140)
12-27 01:42:32.095: E/AndroidRuntime(753):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:name` (instead of `class`):

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

I think `class="myfragment"` is used by **`SupportMapFragment`**,
whereas `android:name="myfragment"` is used with **`MapFragment`**.

You can see this tutorial for more details: [See the step 5](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, updated that info - was still getting the error - it turns out to be that am referring to Google Play services r13 - trying to download r10 or r12 for example to work (like for like)

Answer (score 0):

You may already be too late, but for those looking for a solution that would have only put this tag in the Manifest as a child of "application"

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```